# Setting index.php as new home page in ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, redirect, nginx, routes

I am already having ruby running site(www.example.com).
Now i want to change current home page to new index.php(simple php page not ruby page). 
I Have uploaded my new index.php page into path:

```
/var/www/example/current/public/
```

Now I am able to view my new page from this URL `www.example.com/index.php`

But I want to view my page from this URL `www.example.com`(this will show only old home page)

I have tried this in routes.rb file

```
root :to => "public/index.php"
```

But no luck so far. I'm puzzled.

Comment: Have you set php files to default index files in your `httpd.conf` as `DirectoryIndex index.php` ?

Comment: `routes.rb` is not responsible for webserver configuration. Use the `httpd.conf` file for that instead if you are using the Apache webserver. Which webserver are you using?

Comment: @hakre I am using Nginx Web Server.

Comment: Please see this forum post: [DirectoryIndex on nginx (nginx.org)](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,5020,5121)

Comment: @hakre I Have tried this also server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     www.example.com;

  index           index.php;
  root            /var/www/example/current/public;
} but it goes to same old page.